# Order list of entities which have lists by string length in inner list

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

Having 2 classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

A list which consists of X employees and 4 questions, which every employee has, is there a way to sort employees dynamically by question answers? Like I press an ascending sort button in a table on "Symptoms" in my react app, so it gives me firstly employees which have a "no" answer at with "Symptoms" type of the question, then "yes" and then "maybe". I can't sort out what LINQ expression could even do this. In my head, I kinda imagine what should I do, but I can't just write the query.

```
var list = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee
            {
                Questions = new List<Question>()
                {
                    new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                }
            },
            new Employee
            {
                Questions = new List<Question>()
                {
                    new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                }
            },
            new Employee
            {
                Questions = new List<Question>()
                {
                    new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                    new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                }
            }
        };
```

My friend said that I should write a comparer, but I don't quite understand how to use them specifically here

Comment: Could you please make it that the code compiles?

Comment: With [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby), you can select with what to order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LinQ's expression "OrderBy".

On a list-object called listEmployees ordering by Answer == "No" at the top of the list, the code would look like this:

```
        list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Questions.First(y => y.Type == "Symptoms").Answer == "No").ToList();
```

Maybe the ToList() function isn't needed in your code.

Here's a code snippet with your list and classes:

[Code Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vILCJO)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        },
        new Employee
        {
            Questions = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
            }
        }
    };
    Console.WriteLine("----------BEFORE ORDERBY---------");
    PrintEmployeeList(list);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------\n\n");
    
    // You can change "Yes" to "No" if you want the "No" first.
    list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Questions.First(y => y.Type == "Symptoms").Answer == "No").ToList();
    
    Console.WriteLine("----------AFTER ORDERBY----------");
    PrintEmployeeList(list);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
}

static void PrintEmployeeList(List<Employee> list)
{
    foreach(Employee employee in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(employee.Questions[0].Answer);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't link to external sites without putting the key content in your answer. Links get broken. We don't want your answer broken.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Didn't come up with this subquery using `First()`, so I don't quite understand how this works

Comment: @MixaKonan You could basically just use Questions[0], because the first in all of employees questions is the question-type of Symptoms. With the .First() and the condition type == "Symptoms" you search for the Question linked to the Symptoms Question  and you get the First of the Questions linked with that condition true. You won't get for example the Travel Question Answer on accident.

Answer (score 0):

1, Your "Question" class was missing the "Type" property.
But after adding that property code looks ok.
2, When you add testing data, make them better. Your data are already sorted because all questions have the same answer and that is "yes".

I little bit edited you test data:

```
var list = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "John",
                    Questions = new List<Question>()
                    {
                        new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Yes"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                    }
                },
                new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "Emma",
                    Questions = new List<Question>()
                    {
                        new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "Maybe"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                    }
                },
                new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = "Bill",
                    Questions = new List<Question>()
                    {
                        new Question() {Type = "Symptoms", Answer = "No"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Travel", Answer = "No"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Contact", Answer = "Maybe"},
                        new Question() {Type = "Test", Answer = "Yes"}
                    }
                }
            };
```

After that I made lambda expression:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Questions.Where(q => q.Type == "Symptoms").FirstOrDefault().Answer
        switch
        {
            "No" => 3,
            "Yes" => 2,
            "Maybe" => 1,
            _ => 0
        }).ToList();
```

Result is:
On position 1. is Bill
On position 2. is John
On position 3. is Emma

I am so sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: You can get rid of `Where`:  `... x => x.Questions.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Type == "Symptoms")?.Answer ...`. Please, note `?.`: if you put `FirstOrDefault` i.e. you find `Default` part necessary, you should be ready for defaut, i.e. for `null` and that's why `?.` is expected instead of `.`

Comment: No, you understood the way I meant it to be. I'm not sure there's going to be only 3 answers in the project, so switch is not good option here, sorry for not giving enough information. And I didn't even know you could use switch that way. And anyways thanks for the answer!